# Need to create an array of arrays for each string

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, split

So I have data that looks something like this:

```
>> print data
"12345","string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"
"67890","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"
```

I want to be able to put each line as an array, into an array. So in the end, I want it to look something like this:

```
>> print array_data
[["12345","string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"],
["67890","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"]]
```

I have tried a few things and this is the closest I got:

```
>> temp_list = []
>> for line in data.splitlines(): temp_list.append([line])
>> print temp_list
[['"12345","string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"'],
['"67890","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"']]
```

I am getting that single quote around each array. How should I proceed to get the result that I am looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're still confused, check out how quotes work in Python to indicate strings: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast` and `split`

#### setup

```
import ast
d = '''
"12345","string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"
"67890","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"
'''
templist=[]
```

Then just

```
for line in d.strip().splitlines(): 
    templist.append([ast.literal_eval(st) for st in line.split(',')])
```

Notice that you can also make a oneliner using list comprehension

```
templist = [[ast.literal_eval(st) for st in line.split(',')] for line in d.strip().splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> data
'"12345","string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"\n"67890","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"'
```

You can do (if the `'` do not otherwise indicate csv fields that might have `,` in them!):

```
>>> [line.replace('"','').split(',') for line in data.splitlines()]
[['12345', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5'], ['67890', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10']]
```

Or you can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to properly handle commas in the fields:

```
>>> import csv
>>> [list(e) for e in csv.reader(data.splitlines())]
[['12345', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5'], ['67890', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

d = '''\
"12345","string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"
"67890","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"'''

l = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(d), header=None, dtype='object').values
```

And you have l:

```
[['12345', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5'],
 ['67890', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) and [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io) modules from the standard library:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

d = '''"12345","string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"
"67890","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"'''

res = list(csv.reader(StringIO(d)))

print(res)

[['12345', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5'],
 ['67890', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10']]
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there.

```
>> temp_list = []
>> temp_list = [list(eval(line)) for line in data.splitlines()]
>> print temp_list
[['12345', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5'], ['67890', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10']]
```

Comment: If you downvote a answer, also provide a reason for it.